# Import PhoneGap project into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I followed [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide]) user guide. In the step, including the project as Android Project from Existing Code I browse to `C:\Users\user\workspace\hello` and then I run into the following issue:

[image: eclipse]

Which project folder I should import?

Comment: Did you get any work around?

Answer (score 0):

You should import only inside your platform folder.

Your final import will be like this on eclipse.

[image]

Comment: I also use eclipse, but I do not understand what does it mean that I should only import into my platform folder? I edited my start post, for me it was not possible to add a picture before.

Comment: you need to remove all the projects from the eclipse and import it again one more time.

Comment: Ok , but which one I should import, all of them?

Comment: But it is one project and if I select all it looks like five projects. I'm confused about the structure.